# complex valued neural network (CVNN) error divergence

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am currently working with my undergraduate thesis on complex valued neural network(CVNN).My topic is based on **Single-layered complex-valued neural network for real-valued classification problems**.I am using gradient-descent learning rule to classify a dataset given below:

[Data Set](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4S_GqH-QlpNejF6bFFYMWtaMHc/edit?usp=drive_web&pli=1)

The **alogorithm** i used here can be found on **page 946** of the following PDF labeled as **Complex valued neuron (CVN) Model**.The main algorithm can be on **section 3** of that topic

[Algorithm of CVN Model](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By1rt82JtNxQMXNfeVhVcTBwUEk/edit)

But instead of getting convergence,**my error curve has shown divergent characteristics**.Here is my output of error curve.

[error curve at CVNN implementation](http://i39.tinypic.com/24m5oxh.jpg)

I am simulating the code behind this on **MATLAB**.My implementation is also given below:

```
clc
clear all
epoch=1000;
n=8;
%x=real input value
in=dlmread('Diabetes1.txt');
x=in(1:384,1:8);
%d=desired output value
out=dlmread('Diabetes1.txt');
data_1=out(1:384,9);
data_2=out(1:384,10);


%m=complex representation of input
 m=(cos((pi).*(x(:,:)-0))+1i*sin((pi).*(x(:,:)-0)));
% 
%research
%m=i.*x(:,:)
%m=x(:,:)+i.*x(:,:)
%Wih=weight
%
  %m=x(:,:).*(cos(pi./4)+i.*sin(pi./4));

  Wih1 =0.5* exp(1i * 2*pi*rand(8,1));
  Wih2 =0.5* exp(1i * 2*pi*rand(8,1));

 %Pih=bias

  Pih1 =0.5*exp(1i * 2*pi*rand(1,1));
  Pih2 =0.5*exp(1i * 2*pi*rand(1,1));

 for ite=1:epoch 
%     www(ite)=ite;
     E_Total=0;
     E1t=0;
     E2t=0;
     for j=1:384

     %blr=learning rate    
     blr=0.1;

     %cpat=current pattern
     cpat = m(j,:);
     z1=cpat*Wih1+Pih1;
     u1=real(z1);
     v1=imag(z1);
     fu1=1/(1+exp(-u1));
     fv1=1/(1+exp(-v1));

     %y=actual output
     %for activation function 1
      y1=sqrt((fu1).^2+(fv1).^2);

     %for activation function 2
    % y1=(fu1-fv1).^2;
     error1=(data_1(j,1)-y1);
     E1=((data_1(j,1)-y1).^2);

     t11=1./(1+exp(-u1));
     f11=t11.*(1-t11);
     t21=1./(1+exp(-v1));
     f21=t21.*(1-t21);

     %for activation function 1
      r1= blr.*(data_1(j,1)-y1).*((t11.*f11)./y1)+i.*blr.*(data_1(j,1)-y1).*((t21.*f21)./y1);

     %for activation function 2
   %r1=2.*blr.*(data_1(j,1)-y1).*(t11-t21).*f11+1i.*2.*blr.*(data_1(j,1)-y1).*(t21-t11).*f21;
%      
     Pih1=Pih1+r1;
     Wih1= Wih1+(conj(m(j,:)))'.*r1;


     %////////////////////////////////////////////////

     %cpat=current pattern


     z2=cpat*Wih2+Pih2;
     u2=real(z2);
     v2=imag(z2);
     fu2=1./(1+exp(-u2));
     fv2=1./(1+exp(-v2));
%          fu2=tanh(u2);
%          fv2=tanh(v2);

     %y=actual output

     %for activation function 1
       y2=sqrt((fu2).^2+(fv2).^2);

     %for activation function 2
     % y2=(fu2-fv2).^2;
     error2=(data_2(j,1)-y2);
     E2=((data_2(j,1)-y2).^2);

     t12=1./(1+exp(-u2));
     f12=t12.*(1-t12);
     t22=1./(1+exp(-v2));
     f22=t22.*(1-t22);

     %for activation function1
     r2= blr.*(data_2(j,1)-y2).*((t12.*f12)./y2)+i.*blr.*(data_2(j,1)-y2).*((t22.*f22)./y2);

     %for activation function 2
     %r2=2*blr*(data_2(j,1)-y2)*(t12-t22)*f12+1i*2*blr*(data_2(j,1)-y2)*(t22-t12)*f22;

     Pih2=Pih2+r2;
     Wih2= Wih2+(conj(m(j,:)))'.*r2;
     %///////////////////////////////////////////////

      E1t=E1+E1t;
      E2t=E2+E2t;
      E_Total=(E1+E2+E_Total);
      E1;
      E2;

     end
      Err=E_Total/(2.*384);
     figure(1)
     plot(ite,Err,'b--')
     hold on;
     %figure(1)


 end


dlmwrite('weight.txt',Wih1)
dlmwrite('weight.txt', Wih2, '-append', ...
   'roffset', 1, 'delimiter', ' ')
dlmwrite('weight.txt', Pih1, '-append', ...
   'roffset', 1, 'delimiter', ' ')
dlmwrite('weight.txt', Pih2, '-append', ...


'roffset', 1, 'delimiter', ' ')
```

I still could not figure out reason behind this opposite characteristics on the dataset.So any kind of help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing gradient descent, a very common debugging technique is to check whether the gradient you calculated actually matches the numerical gradient of your loss function.

That is, check

```
(f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx==f'(x)*dx
```

for a variety of small dx.  Usually try along each dimension, as well as in a variety of random directions.  You also want to do this check for a variety of value of x.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a glance at this [blog](https://giggleliu.github.io/complex_bp/) for complex back-propagation.

For **holomorphic** functions, complex BP are fairly straight forward.

For **non-holomorphic** functions (every CVNN must have at least one non-holomorphic function), they need careful treat.